# jQuery Table Forms

Tags: php, jquery

What is a standardized way for submitting jQuery forms that are table based?

I understand this question is somewhat arbitrary, I've seen plugins and looked for examples on how to do this, but I am lost.

I'm sure someone here has experience in this.

The problem really is how exactly do I wrap the table in a form (or a form in a table) without breaking the rules and screwing up jQuery selectors and such?

Comment: Only two options: Either complete `table` inside `form`, or `form` inside a `td` … everything else would be invalid HTML.

Comment: Okay. I've gone over these two options. Both seem highly inefficient. Put a table inside a form, then you have to submit all the data or find a way to only submit part of the data (which finding a way to submit all the data is somewhat bad practice because that means I have to write specialized jQuery to submit them.

The other option would also be inefficient as you would have a form for each stitch of data you want to enter which means different form handlers on the backend or again a way to specify which data is entered.

Which do you suggest?

Comment: _“Which do you suggest?”_ – a proper description of the _actual_ problem, instead of such a vague question.

Comment: A description would be as simple as a form to update tabular data. Let's say, and admin form managing users.

Comment: Yeah – and? Still no actual problem here.

Comment: No, I'm just looking for the right way to do things because I don't know how. I'm lost.

Comment: Still unclear _what exactly_ those “things” are. If you do not want to submit _all_ the data of a form, but only parts of it – then _of course_ you will have to write some JS code to only select/submit those parts. But having that requirement on the one hand, and on the other considering writing the code to fulfill that requirement “bad practice” makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've usually just use

```
<form>
    <table>
    </table>
</form>
```

As long as you close the tags and have everything nested properly you should be good otherwise it will break the html.

Comment: I'm thinking of a table that displays tabular data that needs to be updated per table row. It would be great if I were allowed to do something like: <table><tr><form><td>[input]</td><td>[input]</td></form></tr></table> but that messes with my jQuery selectors.

Comment: I would just use the form table layout like I previously wrote and when I submit the form with ajax, I would only send the data for that one input element and that would be pretty simple. Hope that helps.